# How can I test android UI pages containing signIn and then landing page acessible through deep link using espresso?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have an android app. the first page is sign in page. then once successful login there are set of pages accessible through deep links. all these pages have their own different deep links. I am trying to write espresso test script which automates the signIn page and then checks whether a right activity page is displayed or not for each deep link?